# Trying to install/enable XRDP on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 18.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, remmina

I am trying to install XRDP onto Ubuntu, I have tried many different steps and keep coming across the same error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am brand new to Linux over all as I just downloaded yesterday. My end goal is to use my desktop with windows while running my laptop with Ubuntu as a VM. I am planning on using mRemoteNG as the access point on my desktop (Windows)... if that's relevant. I also have Remmina installed on the laptop (Ubuntu).

I am also new to this so maybe that's showing here...

I have pasted below my Ubuntu install

Version of Ubuntu
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

system         GE62 6QD (Default string)
processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60G
memory         16GiB System memory
disk           1TB HGST HTS721010A9
There's also a GTX960M that doesn't show

Comment: xrdp https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xrdp&searchon=names ... Install : `sudo apt install xrdp` → The **universe** repo must be enabled.

Comment: I went ahead and pulled the repositories for Universe and I did multiverse but it says I already have installed. After this I went ahead and tried to re-download and got same error. 

gabriel@gabriel-GE62-6QD:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
gabriel@gabriel-GE62-6QD:~$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
'multiverse' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

Edit: Did I do it correctly? If not, please correct me. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Strange. Please upload a copy of /etc/apt/sources.list , as `sources.list.txt` to Dropbox .... and edit your question to include a **shared** link to the file.